# Nodejs Module exports result set

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am new in Nodejs trying to export site_setting table values using sequelize any help highly appriciated.

Here is my Table
[setting table here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6iEZ.png)

> Blockquote

```
`const sequelizeConn = require("./database");
var arrResult = new Object();
function getSiteData(){
  settingResult = await sequelizeConn
  .query("SELECT * FROM `site_settings`")
  .then((data) => {
    //  return data;
    data[0].map((res, index) => {
      arrResult[res["setting_title"]] = res["setting_value"];
    });
    // console.log(arrResult);
    return arrResult;
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });

}

module.exports.siteData =getSiteData();


// in other file
var obj = require("./app/config/assets.config");
console.log(obj.SITE_TITLE);  // undefined
`
```

> Blockquote

Answer (score 0):

where is config file bro.
i suggest to share your code with github link that will be easy to debug

Comment: thank you for your response sorry don't have any github link
Its just a simple function which get the site settings from database tables like
1-your site name, 
2-site email address,
3-profile path,
4-images path, 
5-phone number,
etc
i need these column values so i can use it in my site.

Answer (score 0):

if you getting your data with your getSiteDate()
then use `module.exports = getSiteDate()` directly
and import it using

```
const sitedata = require('your file path')
```

Comment: thank you its working any other shortcut becuase my db table contains email, site Name , email  which i need everwhere in the site.

Comment: if its useful then upvote it so others can find useful.